# How do I specify which rules allow and disallow form submission with jQuery Validation?

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, jquery-validate

I'm using the jQuery plugin [jQuery Validation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) for the validation of form fields. I've written some custom rules as well as using default rules and they all work fine at the moment. If a field doesn't validate, the form cannot be submitted until the offending field validates.

However, I have just been asked to make a change to the validation for a particular field using a custom rule, such that the validation rules stay the same and the validation error message appear if the field does not validate but that the form can still be submitted.

Is there a native way to allow for such a request on a per field/rule basis? If not, what would be the best way to add this functionality within the framework of jQuery Validation?

Comment: How would posting my code help? The current code works fine and is an unremarkable implementation of jQuery Validation. My question concerns whether a specific feature is or is not available in the plugin, I don't see how my existing code is pertinent in this scenario.

Comment: Posting your code helps in three ways... 1)  It helps the future reader understand how the problem might relate to an answer.  2)  It helps the person answering to provide a working demo using your own code.  3)  It might help somebody come up with a workaround for you. (I would have actually included one in my answer otherwise)  After all, you want to toggle a message on a field, and by not showing your markup, an answerer would have to write HTML markup from scratch in order to show you a workaround in a jsFiddle demo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "I have just been asked to make a change to the validation for a particular field using a custom rule, such that the validation rules stay the same and the validation error message appear if the field does not validate but that the form can still be submitted."

The whole point of the jQuery Validation plugin is to *block* submission based on your specified rules.

The built-in `addMethod` method works by displaying an error (blocking submission) when your custom function returns `false`.  To allow submission, this function must return `true`, but then no message would be displayed.

I don't see how what you request is possible without rewriting the plugin.

Otherwise, a simple workaround would be to write a separate function attached to the one field's blur or click event handler that toggles a `<label>` in the same location as a validation error would appear.  Something like...

```
$('input#myField').on('blur', function() {
    // your custom validation
    if ( /* some arbitrary rule */ ) {
        // failed your test, show message
        $('label#myLabel').show();
    } else {
        // passed your test, hide message
        $('label#myLabel').hide();
    }
});
```

Although, I recommend against doing any of this as it runs counter to the way the average user expects a form to behave.

Comment: I know it's a counter-intuitive to how the plugin is supposed to work but it's a task which has been assigned to me which I cannot simply refuse. I didn't think there was such an option in the plugin but I thought I would ask just in case before rolling my own.